# how to get the first galley image value in multidimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

Here i having one multidimensional using this array `productId` wise i am making one more array,from this array i having  `Galery` array, from this i have to take `first` prodcutImage value, i don't how can achive this, if any one update my asnwer

> I having array like this

```
print_r($productByCode)

    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [productId] => 5
            [adminproductId] => 1Delivery00123
            [categoryName] => Computer Accessories
            [brandName] => Dell
            [title] => Dell Inspiron 5000 Series 5547 5555 5557 5558 Internal Laptop Keyboard  (Black)
            [subTitle] => Dell Keyboard
            [price] => 200
            [discountType] => Percentage
            [discountValue] => 20
            [afterDiscount] => 160
            [shipppingAmount] => 150
            [taxPercentage] => 25
            [Galery] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [gId] => 13
                            [productId] => 5
                            [prodcutImage] => 1.jpeg
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [gId] => 14
                            [productId] => 5
                            [prodcutImage] => 2.jpeg
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [gId] => 15
                            [productId] => 5
                            [prodcutImage] => 3.jpeg
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

> I have tried like this

```
$itemArray = array
(
  $productByCode[0]["productId"]=>array
  (
    'categoryName'=>$productByCode[0]["categoryName"], 
    'productId'=>$productByCode[0]["productId"], 
    'brandName'=>$productByCode[0]["brandName"], 
    'subTitle'=>$productByCode[0]["subTitle"], 
    'quantity'=>$Qty_total,
    'price'=>$productByCode[0]["afterDiscount"],
    'taxPercentage'=>$productByCode[0]["taxPercentage"].'%',
    'shipppingAmount'=>$productByCode[0]["shipppingAmount"],
    'qtyprice'=>round($productByCode[0]["afterDiscount"])
  )
);
```

**Current Output**

```
    Array
(
    [5] => Array
        (
            [categoryName] => Computer Accessories
            [productId] => 5
            [brandName] => Dell
            [subTitle] => Dell Keyboard
            [quantity] => 1
            [price] => 160
            [taxPercentage] => 25%
            [shipppingAmount] => 150
            [qtyprice] => 160
        )

)
```

**Expected Output**

```
 Array
(
    [5] => Array
        (
            [categoryName] => Computer Accessories
            [productId] => 5
            [brandName] => Dell
            [subTitle] => Dell Keyboard
            [quantity] => 1
            [price] => 160
            [taxPercentage] => 25%
            [shipppingAmount] => 150
            [qtyprice] => 160
            [prodcutImage] => 1.jpeg
        )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you requirement, You've already tried like this way to assign values to different array element, So just grab the **Galery** value like this using nested array element accessing way & add this element at the last of your array.

`'prodcutImage' => $productByCode[0]['Galery'][0]['prodcutImage']`

So it will like this,

```
$itemArray = array
(
$productByCode[0]["productId"]=>array
(
    'categoryName'=>$productByCode[0]["categoryName"], 
    'productId'=>$productByCode[0]["productId"], 
    'brandName'=>$productByCode[0]["brandName"], 
    'subTitle'=>$productByCode[0]["subTitle"], 
    'quantity'=>$Qty_total,
    'price'=>$productByCode[0]["afterDiscount"],
    'taxPercentage'=>$productByCode[0]["taxPercentage"].'%',
    'shipppingAmount'=>$productByCode[0]["shipppingAmount"],
    'qtyprice'=>round($productByCode[0]["afterDiscount"]),
    'prodcutImage' => $productByCode[0]['Galery'][0]['prodcutImage']
  )
);
```

Comment: i tried your code but i am getting error `Notice: Undefined index: productByCode in C:\xampp5.6`

Comment: Now i got the mistake,and also i rectified `'prodcutImage' => $productByCode[0]['Galery'][0]['prodcutImage']`

Comment: @KaniR Have a look on my edited answer. I just made a silly typo here :) bye the way. best of luck